# Python - quit vlc before completing video file

Tags: python, vlc

The following call quits the vlc player after completing the video.

```
subprocess.call([vlc_path, video_path, '--play-and-exit', '--fullscreen'], shell=False)
```

If I want to quit vlc in 1 hour irrespective of whether video is complete or not, how can I do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to specify `--stop-time <seconds>`:

```
subprocess.call([vlc_path, video_path, '--play-and-exit', 
    '--fullscreen', '--stop-time','3600'], shell=False)
```

From the long help (`vlc -H`):

```
Playback control:
  --input-repeat <integer [-2147483648 .. 2147483647]> 
                             Input repetitions
      Number of time the same input will be repeated
  --start-time <float>       Start time
      The stream will start at this position (in seconds).
  --stop-time <float>        Stop time
      The stream will stop at this position (in seconds).
  --run-time <float>         Run time
      The stream will run this duration (in seconds).
```

Comment: Thank you.Where do I see the help for vlc commandline ?
I get 'vlc: command not found' in my terminal.

Comment: @JaydevKalivarapu asuming you are using `bash`: vlc normally gets added as a command on installation. You could add it as an alias in `.bashrc` : `alias vlc = abs_vlc_path`. If using windows, you need to add vlc.exe to your path as mentioned [here](http://superuser.com/questions/689333/how-to-add-installed-program-to-command-prompt-in-windows)

Comment: -bash: abs_vlc_path: command not found
Am I doing something evidently wrong ?

Comment: @JaydevKalivarapu sorry, I was not clear enough. By abs_vlc_path I mean the absolute path to your vlc binary, eg. `/usr/bin/vlc` in some flavours of linux

Comment: Oops, I just got what you meant {alias vlc=/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC}. It works like a charm, Thank you :)